# want to make UI thread wait while Asynctask is working in background

Tags: android, json, multithreading, android-asynctask

I am making an app in which I use `Asynctack` to fetch login details for me

User enters username and password and I the following function from a different class

```
static int success;
public static boolean authenticate(final String emailId , final String password , final ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    data = new Data();
new AsyncTask<Void , Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... param) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username" , emailId));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password" , password));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_login, "POST", params);

            try {
                success = json.getInt("success");
                if (success ==1){
                    JSONArray student = json.getJSONArray("student");
                    JSONObject jobject = student.getJSONObject(0);

                    ...loading details...
                }



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Authentication error" , e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    }.execute(); 
   if (success==1){
   return true;}
    else return false;

}
```

here I call it

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
                if(Login.authenticate(username,password,progressDialog)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Authenticated\nWelcome " + Login.data.Fullname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ..calling next activity...
                    ...bla bla bla...
                }
                else Toast.makeText(this, "Authentication Failed" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

In this IF condition the `ProgressDialog` appears and with that 2nd toast appears i.e. Authentication Failed and nothing happens

I think I know whats the problem here but cant figure it out

I think UI thread must wait till the `Asynctask` completes its task and then return anything

Comment: You'r using deprecated code. So just migrate with _Volley_ or _Retrofit_ or _OkHttp_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think UI thread must wait till the AsyncTask completes its task and
>   then return anything

When calling `AsyncTask.execute` UI Thread not wait for complete and return from  AsyncTask.

But `onPostExecute` is a method which is called on UI Thread when `doInBackground` so do all work which want to execute according to AsyncTask result inside  `onPostExecute` method like want to show Toast message or start a new Activity,...

```
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
         if (success==1){
           // start new Activity here
         }
         else {
           // show fail message 
         }
    }
```

Comment: cant use it as the `AsyncTask` is inside a static method so `startActivity()` wont work

Comment: @Shubham: Why `authenticate ` method is static ?

Comment: @Shubham: ok either make it non-static or pass Context as parameter to `authenticate ` for accessing or starting `startActivity ` method

Comment: because I use it outside its class and I cant make its class object

Comment: @Shubham: ok then  pass Context as parameter to authenticate for accessing or starting startActivity method

Comment: selecting the answer thanks alot you saved alot of time

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Suggest him to use latest code. _List<NameValuePair>_ is deprecated now !

Answer (score 1):

You are going in wrong direction. Why make main thread wait when async task is executing?

Instead you can achieve that using following steps

1. Show ProgressDialog
2. start async task and let it execute.
3. in `onPostExecute()` notify UI to stop the progressDialog